# Login with cookies disabled

Tags: bug, openid, login, cookies

When I try to log in with cookies disabled, the OpenID login page shows a link to log in manually.

> ## Third Party Cookies Appear To Be Disabled
>
> You can [continue and log in manually](https://stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate?openid_identifier=https%3a%2f%2fopenid.stackexchange.com%2f) however.

After I follow that link and enter my e-mail and password, I get taken to the page 
https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/login/submit which says

> ### Not Found
>
> This page could not be found.

I'm using Opera 12.00.